# Group 64 picture boxes into picturebox array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, picturebox

I created 64 picture boxes using the GUI. Now I would like to group these picture boxes into a picturebox array because I need it to constantly update the pictures in the said picture boxes.

I have the following code:

```
private PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray= new PictureBox[64]; //Initialize array to group picture boxes into picture box array

  private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref pictureBoxArray);
    }

public static void ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray)
    {
        foreach(PictureBox index in pictureBoxArray)
        {
        //Some code to do the following:
        pictureBoxArray[0]=pictureBox1; //this is the name of the pictureBox on the GUI
        pictureBoxArray[1]=pictureBox2;
        pictureBoxArray[2]=pictureBox3;
        .
        .
        .
        pictureBoxArray[63]=pictureBox64;

       //

    }
```

I have seen commands of Controls.ofType but I don't seem to understand it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: why is this in a foreach statement?

Comment: Because I have to go through the whole array(?) (just a suggestion, any change is welcome)

Comment: I still don't get your problem, do you want a better way of writing your code or you want to do something else with you code?

Comment: Also you don't need **ref** for your parameter, array is a class and it's **ref** by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after sometime I came to use the following method:

```
private PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray = new PictureBox[64]; //Initialize array to group picture boxes into picture box array

private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref pictureBoxArray);
    }

public void ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray)
{
        int i = 0;
        string NameofPictureBox;
        string PictureBoxNumber;

        foreach (var item in groupBox_DataLayer.Controls)
        {
            if (item is PictureBox)
            {
                NameofPictureBox = ((PictureBox)item).Name;
                PictureBoxNumber = Regex.Match(NameofPictureBox, @"\d+").Value; // \d+ is regex for integers only
                i = Int32.Parse(PictureBoxNumber);  //Convert only number string to int
                i = i - 1;  //bcs of index of array starts from 0-63, not 1-64
                pictureBoxArray[i] = (PictureBox)item; //put PictureBox object in desired position
            }

        }
}
```

This works completely for me, I had problems with sorting but now everything is working. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This code add all pictureboxes of your Form to your pictureBoxArray

```
private PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray;
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     pictureBoxArray = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
}
```

**"this"** refers to Form, if you want to add picture boxes of another container like **groupbox** or **any container** just **replace** **"this"** with the **name of your container**.

If you want to sort them at descending order you can use **OrderByDescending** instead of **OrderBy**.

**The complete code can be like this:**

```
private static PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray;

public static void ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ContainerControl container)
{
    pictureBoxArray = container.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
}
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(this);//Or Whatever container like groupbox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're stuck with the design of the form and the 64 individual `pictureBoxNN` properties, basic reflection can populate the array as needed.  I don't think `Controls` can be guaranteed to have the right ordering.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    pictureBoxArray[i] = (PictureBox)GetType().GetProperty("pictureBox" + (i + 1)).GetValue(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're not nested in other controls, but placed directly on your Form, you can do this:

```
PictureBox[] pictureBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

For your nested controls you will need to pass through all control containers and check if they contain PictureBox inside it. You could do it this way:

```
private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
    GetAllPictureBoxes(ref pictureBoxes, this.Controls);

    PictureBox[] pictureBoxesArray = pictureBoxes.OrderBy(pb => pb.Name).ToArray();
}

private void GetAllPictureBoxes(ref List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes, Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        if (control.HasChildren)
            GetAllPictureBoxes(ref pictureBoxes, control.Controls);

        if (control is PictureBox)
            pictureBoxes.Add((PictureBox)control);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a LinQ query to search for controls with a certain name:

```
public void ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= pictureBoxArray.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        int count = i;
        pictureBoxArray[i] = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c.Name.ToLower() == "picturebox" + (count + 1)).First();
    }
}
```

You basically loop through the indizes from 0 to 63 and search the picturebox of name "picturebox + (index+1)" and assign it to this index in the array.

This skips problems if the source pictureboxes are not sorted in the `this.Controls` collection.

Given your comment about the groupbox: In this case the pictureboxes are not part of `this.Controls` and you would need to replace the query with

```
pictureBoxArray[i] = (PictureBox)groupboxName.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c.Name.ToLower() == "picturebox" + (count + 1)).First();
```

Comment: c => c is this a lambda expression ?

Comment: Yes it is. It is part of the LinQ query. In this case `c` is the current element in Controls that is being compared to the given name.

Comment: I'm still getting a Null reference exception when I try to print names of the items from the array. I have replaced this with the name of the group box.

Comment: Also user2946329 method FIRST method works, but instead of this.Controls is changed to groupBox_DataLayer.Controls. It works but the names are not in order. Maybe I should use his method and then just sort the array ?

Comment: Hard to say why you get the exception. I tested this method and it selects the pictureboxes just fine and places them in the array. Where exactly do you get the exception? Are you sure you call `this.InitializeComponent()` first to actually create the boxes? The call should be in the form's constructor.

Comment: I call initialize  component in public Main(), and then I call ConvertGuiPBtoGuiPbArray(ref pictureBoxArray); in   private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)